# How do you specify column compression algorithm in duckdb?

Tags: duckdb

I've read [DuckDB Lightweight Compression](https://duckdb.org/2022/10/28/lightweight-compression.html) and understand that DuckDB is designed to choose the best compression strategy automatically, but would like to know if it is possible to give hints in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements to explicitly set the compression.

I didn't see anything in the [CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/create_table#syntax) documentation either.

[This github issue comment](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/3106#issuecomment-1045325727) (copied below) implies that it is possible.

> The system itself will automatically choose the best compression option available. Overriding the automatic compression detection and choosing a compression option manually should really only be used for debugging/profiling purposes or in edge cases when the system makes one choice (e.g. best compression ratio) but you want another (e.g. best performance).